# How to group concat on this result set in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-concat

How to modify and apply concatination on the following result

This is the first table:

```
DECLARE @item_tbl TABLE ( ItemId INT,Title NVARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @item_tbl VALUES (1,'Title 1'),(2,'Title 2')
,(3,'Title 3'),(4,'Title 4'),(5,'Title 5')
```

This is the second table:

```
DECLARE @item_ref TABLE (ReferenceId INT, FromItemId INT,
ToItemId INT) 
INSERT INTO @item_ref VALUES(1,1,2),(2,1,3),(3,4,5),(4,5,1)
```

There is some interelation between table 1 & table 2

```
SELECT AA.Title, ISNULL(BB.Hasreferenceto,'') Hasreferenceto,
ISNULL(CC.Isreferencedfrom,'') Isreferencedfrom FROM  
@item_tbl AA LEFT JOIN ( SELECT A.FromItemId, B.Title Hasreferenceto
FROM @item_ref A LEFT JOIN @item_tbl B  ON A.ToItemId =B.ItemId
 ) BB ON AA.ItemId = BB.FromItemId
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT C.ToItemId, D.Title Isreferencedfrom 
FROM @item_ref C LEFT JOIN @item_tbl D ON C.FromItemId = D.ItemId
) CC ON AA.ItemId = CC.ToItemId
```

This is giving me:

```
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title   | Hasreferenceto   | Isreferencedfrom   |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 1 | Title 2          | Title 5            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 1 | Title 3          | Title 5            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 2 |                  | Title 1            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 3 |                  | Title 1            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 4 | Title 5          |                    |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 5 | Title 1          | Title 4            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
```

What i want is:

```
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title   | Hasreferenceto   | Isreferencedfrom   |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 1 | Title 2, Title 3 | Title 5            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 2 |                  | Title 1            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 3 |                  | Title 1            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 4 | Title 5          |                    |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
| Title 5 | Title 1          | Title 4            |
+---------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Can someone help in this please?

Comment: Use stuff statement

Comment: Can you help me with the query please. Modify and Post as an answer.